# Sausage made of cheese and meat?

Tags: cheese, sausages

Is there some kind of [sausage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sausage) that blends some kind of cheese with meat? In Brazil we have a kind of cheese that has almost the same shape of a sausage, I guess this could exist.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[Cheese Kranksy](http://www.hellers.co.nz/gourmet-sausages/detail/5-gourmet/flypage/62-cheese-kransky?sef=hcfp) or Kasekrainer is the common sausage with cheese. Around 10% cheese seems typical

[image]

They taste great, and are very popular with children

Answer (score 5):

I know that there is a German meat and cheese sausage called käsewurst/kaesewurst.  In the US we also now have "novelty" sausages that combine meat and cheese:

- [Smoked Cheddar & Chicken](http://millerpoultry.host-bnin.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Miller-Poultry-sausage-smoked-cheese.jpg)
- [Chicken, Garlic, and Gruyere](http://themellowjihadi.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Aidells-Sausage-Roasted-Garlic-and-Gruyere-Cheese.jpg)
- [Italian Sausage with Cheeses](http://www.johnsonville.com/products/four-cheese-italian-sausage/image/italianFourCheeseSausageLinks.png)

Comment: I MUST eat this.

Comment: Do they ship to Brazil? :p

Answer (score 3):

I was in Netherlands this summer, and we bought a smoked cheese that had small bits of ham inside. The cheese was formed as a thick sausage:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide me the name of it?